# Схлопывается картинка

Tags: html, css

```css
.comment{
  z-index: 10;

  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;


  &__cont{
    background-color: @green;
    padding: 50px 5px 45px;


  }

  &__img{
    width: 126px;
    height: 126px;
    margin-right:20px;

  }

  &__block{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  &__quote{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
  }

  &__article{
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;

  }

  &__article-pos{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }

  &__author{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }


}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
            <div class="comment__cont">
                <div class="small-container1">
            <div class="row nomarg">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ">
                    <div class="comment__block comment__block-marg">
                        <img src="image/list-img-1.png" alt="" class="comment__img">
                        <div class="comment__text">
                            <i class="fa fa-quote-left comment__quote" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <p class="comment__article comment__article-pos">Guys, you rock! Made a purchase at your store recently.
                                The order has been shipped and delivered on time. The quality is superb! The price is quite
                                reasonable. Told all my friends about your excellent service and the variety of choice.
                                I think I’ll be your loyal customer
                                in future as well. I wish your store many more years of prosperity.</p>
                            <span class="comment__author">- MARY TABA</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ">
                    <div class="comment__block">
                        <img src="image/list-img-2.png" alt="" class="comment__img">
                        <div class="comment__text">
                            <i class="fa fa-quote-left comment__quote" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <p class="comment__article comment__article-pos">Having the distressing experience with some online shops before
                                decided to say ‘’THANK YOU” to all personnel of this store. You are not only friendly, but deliver really
                                good products in the shortest possible terms. In a word,
                                I am absolutely happy with my purchase and the service. Everything was perfect!</p>
                            <span class="comment__author">- VIRGINIA UBERT</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять как так происходит. И происходит это через раз. Хотя хром показывает что в css картинка 126х126, но фактическая ширина 36.5. Что на картинку может так влиять?

Comment: добавить картинку в div - проблема решена. Никогда не использовать картинку в открытом состоянии во флексах. Или ставить min и max width у картинки. Но лучше все же поместить в div

Comment: Спасибо за решение и совет!